# iOS 10 - Blurred Background doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiblureffect

Does anyone has problems with the UIBlurEffect on iOS10 ?
For some Reason the background of my button etc just gets a bit transparent and doesn't blurr anymore....

```
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight)
    blurBackgroundView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurBackgroundView.frame = frame
    button = UIButton(frame: frame)   
    blurBackgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    addSubview(blurBackgroundView)
    addSubview(button)
```

that's how the code looks....

If I change UIBlurEffectStyle.ExtraLight to UIBlurEffectStyle.Prominent based on the new documentation the Button is just clear... so no color at all!

Answer (score 0):

Add whatever you want **not** to be blurred to your `blurBackgroundView`. So instead of:

```
addSubview(blurBackgroundView)
addSubview(button)
```

You'll have to:

```
blurBackgroundView.addSubview(button)
addSubview(blurBackgroundView)
```

Now every item in the current view, below your `blurBackgroundView` will get blurred, while your button will stay as it is.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately it doesn't change anything. for some reason it's just blur under iOS10 ...